# Do you have to have file I/O inside the Activity class?

Tags: android

I have code that is inside my Activity class to load and save a file.  It works fine.  The code saves the contents of cFavretClass.  I'm trying to clean up the code, so I moved the file i/o into the cFavret Class.

I cannot get the code to compile. Now I get an error saying `openFileOutput is undefined in type cFavrets`.

I'm assuming that this method was declared in Googles Activity Class?
Does this mean all file I/O must be in the activity class?

```
boolean Save()
{
  String FILENAME = "hello_file";

  try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
  }
  // just catch all exceptions and return false
  catch (Throwable t) {
    return false;
  }       
  return true;
}  

boolean Load()
{
  String FILENAME = "hello_file";
  try {
    FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);   
    buffer[0]=0;
    fos.read(buffer);
    fos.close();
  }
  // just catch all exceptions and return false
  catch (Throwable t) {
  // maybe file does not exist, try creating it
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean all file I/O must be in the activity class?

No, but the method in question is called from a context - just pass a context into the constructor of this `cFavretClass` (or to the method itself, if you prefer):

```
Context mContext;
public cFavretClass(Context context) {
  mContext = context;
}

...
  // in your methods:
  mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME);
```

Comment: Hi,In the Activty class how can I get the context??? I'm trying Context mContext;
        mContext=Context; not working

Comment: The activity is the context - just pass `this`

Answer (score 0):

As JRaymond explained, `openFileOutput` is a method of `Context` of which `Activity` is derived. This method is special insofar as it allows you to create files, which are **private** to your application.

You can use the normal Java I/O classes too, to write to the external storage (SD-Card) but those files will be readable by everybody.